# Images not showing in codepen

Tags: web-hosting, codepen

I have a code which I need to share so I pasted in from Visual Studio Code into code pen and replace all my image links with imgur links but when I save the code on codepen it doesn't show up.

I've tried uploading to different picture sharing websites but none of them seems to work or sometimes they just dissapear

`<a href="#"><img src="https://images.app.goo.gl/PH9vzQEL6deb152b7" alt="logo"></a>` 
This is a simple code i used but the image just refuses to appear.

I just need to image to show up, if there is any way to share my website without publishing it to the web I would like to be informed about it too. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this is](https://www.base64-image.de/) a website that get your image and give you base64 of it and you can put this base64 thing in your src attribute of img element and you are good to go